Copia de listas en c# sin usar IClonable
Necesito devolver una copia de las listas que tengo en cada clase, pero cuando creo una nueva instancia de persona, la listaDeAutos se reinicia y pierde la referencia a los autos ya asignados, que podría ser?
Por ejemplo: Creo persona A, creo y asigno auto X a persona A, la lista se actualiza y guarda X en A. Cuando creo persona B, la lista de autos de A queda en 0
  internal class Persona
  {
      public string DNI { get; set; }
      public string Nombre { get; set; }
      public string Apellido { get; set; }

      List<Auto> ListaDeAutos;

      public Persona()
      {
          ListaDeAutos = new List<Auto>();
      }

      public Persona(Persona persona): this()
      {
          DNI = persona.DNI;
          Nombre = persona.Nombre;
          Apellido = persona.Apellido;
      }

      public void AgregarAuto(Auto auto)
      {
          try
          {
              ListaDeAutos.Add(new Auto(auto));
          }catch(Exception e)
          {
              throw new Exception(e.Message);
          }
      }

      public List<Auto> RetornarAutos()
      {
          List<Auto> autosAux = new List<Auto>();
          foreach (Auto auto in ListaDeAutos)
          {
              autosAux.Add(CrearCopia(auto));
          }

          return autosAux;
      }

      public Auto CrearCopia(Auto auto)
      {
          Auto copyAuto = new Auto(auto);
          return copyAuto;
      }
  }

 internal class Personas
 {
     List<Persona> ListaDePersonas;


     public Personas()
     {
         ListaDePersonas = new List<Persona>();
     }

     public void AgregarPersona(Persona persona)
     {
         ListaDePersonas.Add(new Persona(persona));
     }

     public List<Persona> RetornarPersonas()
     {
         List<Persona> personasAux = new List<Persona>();
         foreach (var persona in ListaDePersonas)
         {
             personasAux.Add(CrearCopia(persona));
         }

         return personasAux;
     }

     public Persona CrearCopia(Persona persona)
     {
         Persona copyPersona = new Persona(persona);
         return copyPersona;
     }
 }

 internal class Autos
 {
     List<Auto> ListaDeAutos;

     public Autos()
     {
         ListaDeAutos = new List<Auto>();
     }

     public void AgregarAuto(Auto auto)
     {
         ListaDeAutos.Add(new Auto(auto));
     }

     public List<Auto> RetornarAutos()
     {
         List<Auto> autosAux = new List<Auto>();
         foreach (Auto auto in ListaDeAutos)
         {
             autosAux.Add(CrearCopia(auto));
         }

         return autosAux;
     }

     public Auto CrearCopia(Auto auto)
     {
         Auto copyAuto = new Auto(auto);
         return copyAuto;
     }
 }

La idea es hacer una copia de todo para respetar el encapsulamiento de cada clase. No utilizo ninguna herramienta extra que brinda c# porque asi lo pide la catedra de la UNI.
Gracias de antemano!

¿Puedes mostrar el código de tu exemplo donde creas Persona A y Persona B etc?
